# Can a vegan ethically buy animal leather knowingly?

Tags: veganism, ethics, leather, economics

My persnickety grandma fancies a Steelcase office chair with 2 choices of seat material: [Brisa ultrafabric](https://finishlibrary.steelcase.com/all-surfaces/brisa-1.html) or [Elmosoft animal leather](http://www.elmoleather.com/furniture/collections/elmosoft.aspx) (see red underlines beneath).  Steelcase apprised her that

> Elmo uses just Scandinavian cows. All Scandinavian cows are dairy cows and are born naturally, grass fed and natural feed. They aren't raised for their beef like South American cows.
>
> [image]

We assume and agree that we can't definitively know the conditions of the cattle whence the hides were plucked. How'd we know if Elmo lies that they never [kill a cow for its hide, but they can take it off a cow that dies of natural causes](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/9av8qt/cmv_you_are_not_a_vegan_if_you_buy_use_leather/e4yhon0/)?

I chose Brisa,  believing that ['the ideal world is one without animals and/or their products for consumption, regardless of how well they've been treated. [So I'm] are placing a negative value on their existence, and to be consistent[,] must believe it's better for them to not exist at all.](https://old.reddit.com/r/vegan/comments/8from4/anyone_else_arrived_at_antinatalism_after_veganism/dy748jy/).

She'd pick  artificial leather, but Steelcase doesn't offer it. Thus she's picking Elmosoft.

#### Her arguments that veganism doesn't forbid animal leather:

1. [As long as you're not creating the demand for these industries, then I don't see any harm.](https://old.reddit.com/r/vegan/comments/bi0gt1/second_hand_leatherwool/elx7qk0/) [But using animal products that you already have isn't against the concept, directly.](https://old.reddit.com/r/vegan/comments/bghdzy/my_car_has_leather_seats/elksxjx/)
2. [Most leather is made from elderly milking cows, or from cows slaughtered for food. So by using the leather, you're not wasting an already dead animal.](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/9av8qt/cmv_you_are_not_a_vegan_if_you_buy_use_leather/e4yf3th/)
3. [Vegan orders an Uber, car arrives and it has [animal] leather upholstery. If they get in the car their money is financing leather. Are they no longer vegan?](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/9av8qt/cmv_you_are_not_a_vegan_if_you_buy_use_leather/e4ye6it/)

#### Her arguments that animal leather is more practical than Brisa.

3. [Cleanup. Dirt/mud, liquids, and crumbs are generally far easier to clean up.](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/2rd3qe/cmv_cloth_car_seats_are_better_than_leather/cnevoxx/)
4. [Leather lasts longer. They'll eventually crack and rip but long after cloth seats do](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/2rd3qe/cmv_cloth_car_seats_are_better_than_leather/cnetenq/).
5. [Leather seats don't take in smells like cloth seats do](https://old.reddit.com/r/changemyview/comments/2rd3qe/cmv_cloth_car_seats_are_better_than_leather/cnetenq/).

Comment: In your edit you say Scandinavian breeds aren't raised for beef. So what happens to the carcass? It's just thrown away after the skin is removed?

Comment: @Nic Hmm, not sure. But my grandma didn't press further, as this suffices to convince us that we won't buy ElmoSoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The leather product (ElmoSoft) sold by this company (Elmo) is definitively NOT taken from a cow that died of natural causes. The clearest proof is from their [supplier code of conduct](http://www.elmoleather.com/media/12297/elmo%20supplier%20code%20of%20conduct%20%202018.pdf) in which they clarify that they will only purchase the skin of cows which were bred for food purposes.

> [Elmo] will deem the products of animal origin ... which have not been obtained from animals bred for food purposes ... to be non-compliant.

On their [their website](http://www.elmoleather.com/furniture/collections/elmosoft.aspx) they indicate that *elmosoft* material is made from "Grain leather from Scandinavian cattle". Many Scandinavian breeds are bred for milking, and another [source](https://www.cumberlandfurniture.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Leather.pdf) confirms this.

> Elmo Leather uses only Scandinavian Dairy Cattle.

To put it bluntly -- that leather is the skin of deceased [dairy cows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icelandic_cattle). It seems bizarre to claim that the product of their life (milk) is not suitable for vegans, yet the product of their death (their skin) is perfectly suitable for vegans. As a practising vegan I would definitely not buy this for myself nor anyone else.

Your grandma's arguments #1 and #2 are economic arguments about byproducts and coproducts. Those arguments are addressed in this other question: [How much is leather a byproduct of meat production?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/how-much-is-leather-a-byproduct-of-meat-production).